# Integral of $[\frac{1}{x}]^{-1}$ on $(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I found in a book this exercise:

> Prove that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{[{\frac{1}{x}}]}dx=+\infty$

In my proof i find that this  integral is finite.

Here is my proof:

By Beppo-Levi:

$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{[{\frac{1}{x}}]}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})}\frac{1}{[{\frac{1}{x}}]}dx$

$\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x <\frac{1}{n} \Longrightarrow n<\frac{1}{x} \leq n+1$

So $[\frac{1}{x}]=n \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{[{\frac{1}{x}}]}=\frac{1}{n}$

Thus the integral is equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})<+\infty$$

Am i missing something?

Comment: Is it possible the source didn't use $[y]$ to denote the floor function?

Comment: It should be clear that the integral is not $\infty$. For $0 < x < 1$, we have $\frac{1}{x}\ge 1$, so $\lfloor1/x\rfloor \ge 1$. Hence $ \frac{1}{\lfloor1/x\rfloor } \le 1$. So the integral cannot exceed $\int_0^1 1\, dx = 1$. Is there a typo in the question maybe?

Comment: @J.G...this is exercise  12 ,page 60 in Measure theory and Integration of G. de Barra

Comment: Maybe it was a typo and he meant the integral of $[\frac{1}{x}]$ on $[0,1]$ which is indeed $+ \infty$

Comment: How is $\left[x \right]$ defined in your book?

Comment: In the book say that $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$

Comment: @MariosGretsas "then it would just be the integral of $x$" only if $[y]$ instead denoted $y$, which would make the brackets pointless. I thought it might be yet another meaning.

Comment: Yes Yes you are right...indeed the brackets in this exercise are not pointless and it is the integer part of $[x]$  if you look at the exercise in the text..But maybe the exercise is wrong..it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, such integral is finite:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\int_{1/(m+1)}^{1/m}\frac{dx}{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}}{m}=\zeta(2)-1. $$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a typo in the orginal excercise, so that the r.h.s. should read $\lt \infty$.

But why not calculate the integral $i = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]}\,dx$ explicitly?
Here $\left[x\right]$ is the integer part of x.

Subsituting $x\to \frac{1}{t}$, $dx\to - \frac{dt}{t^2}$ the integral becomes

$$i = \int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} \frac{1}{\left[t\right]}\,dt$$

Splitting the integration region into parts from $k$ to $k+1$ we get the sum

$$i = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{t^2} \frac{1}{\left[t\right]} \,dt $$

Since $\left[t\right]=k$ for $k\le t \lt{k+1}$ the sum becomes

$$i = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{1}{t^2} \,dt = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)}= \zeta(2) - 1 \simeq 0.644934$$

Comment: Oh, I just saw that Jack was quicker.